# Can a subdomain set a cookie on the parent domain

Tags: html, web, cookies

Suppose I load a website from www.myapp.com

Can it set a cookie on the domain myapp.com, or only read them?

Is there an answer that is standard across all browsers?

Answer (score -1):

**Yes.**
If it specifies the domain as .myapp.com then both myapp.com and subdomain.myapp.com can either read or set it.

Comment: And the subdomain can set it without it being previously set by myapp.com?